# Baking Powder instead of soda error

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Bit of a random one but I had an oven fire yesterday due to grease.  I decided to clean my over as a result but stupidly used baking POWDER rather than soda and wiped it off with vinegar.

Now I am really worried as I have a gas oven, and some of the baking powder has seeped through the holes at the bottom where the naked flame.  Do you have any idea whether this is dangerous?  Will the baking powder ignite or set fire? Or will it just burn off? I'm very worried about what will happen to the oven now.

Comment: For what it’s worth, baking powder = soda in a household environment.

Comment: Baking powder is baking soda with an acid component added.  In your case it should make little difference.  After wetting the acid and carbonate have reacted into a more stable salt. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baking_powder

Answer (score 2):

Baking powder is baking soda ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) plus a mild acid salt or dry acid, such as $\ce{Ca(H2PO4)2}$ or tartaric acid. These ingredients should pose no hazard in a stove unless there is remaining powder blocking a vent hole or gas nozzle. In that case, just use a paper clip or other tool to open the vent.

Tartaric acid is theoretically flammable, but the amount you might have left is so small as to be innocuous. You've probably cleaned the stove about as well as baking soda would, once you remove all obvious deposits of the white powder. *Bon appétit!*